# Bash named pipes, parallel commands and exit status

Tags: bash, exit-status, fifo

I'm trying to use a named pipe so I can keep `stdout` for status output from a long process.  I could use `stderr` for status output, but I'd like to keep that for errors.  Here is an example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
pipe=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo $pipe

dd if=/dev/zero of=$pipe bs=1M count=1024 status=progress & cat $pipe > test.bin

# ¿¿¿ Status of dd command ???

rm $pipe
```

The command isn't exactly what I'm trying to do, but illustrates the combination of using a named pipe for the output of one process feeding into the input of another.  In my application, `dd` is replaced with some long running command, and `cat` with `ssh`.  This would do what I want, but I don't know how to get the status of the `dd` command as `$?` would return the status of the `cat` command.  If this were a pipe, I could use `PIPESTATUS` but that doesn't seem to work for parallel processes.  In the actual application either (or both) commands could fail.

Is there a way to get the status of processes run in parallel?  Is there a better way to accomplish this task using something other than named pipes?

Comment: @hophop There is nothing wrong with the `dd` command in the example.  `dd` is just a stand-in example as I'm not actually using it in the actual application.  I need to know if it fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the exit status of an asynchronous command, you use `wait` on its pid:

```
#!/bin/bash -
pipe=$(mktemp -u) || exit
mkfifo -m 600 -- "$pipe" || exit

dd if=/dev/zero of="$pipe" bs=1M count=1024 status=progress &
dd_pid=$!

cat -- "$pipe" > test.bin
cat_status=$?
wait "$dd_pid"
dd_status=$?

rm -f -- "$pipe"
```

(also fixing some of the obvious mistakes like not checking for success of those `mktemp`/`mkfifo`, unquoted expansions, missing `--`s).

Note that if `dd` (or whatever actual command `dd` is standing-in for in your case) exits before opening `$pipe` for writing, then `cat` will hang on its own read-only `open()` of the fifo indefinitely.

To work around that, you could have the shell open `$pipe` on another fd for the process that will eventually run `dd` making sure the pipe is instantiated as soon as `cat` opens it as well (and assuming `dd` doesn't arbitrarily close that fd before opening `$pipe`):

```
dd if=/dev/zero 3> "$pipe" of="$pipe" bs=1M count=1024 status=progress &
dd_pid=$!
cat -- "$pipe" > test.bin
cat_status=$?
wait "$dd_pid"
dd_status=$?
```

Similarly, if `cat` dies before opening the pipe, you'll have the same symmetrical problem, which you could address the same way.

Instead of a named pipe, if your system has `/dev/fd/n` files, you could probably also use a normal pipe in combination with `/dev/fd/n` and use `bash`'s `$PIPESTATUS` to retrieve the exit statuses:

```
{
  dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/fd/3 bs=1M count=1024 3>&1 >&5 4<&- 5>&- |
    cat /dev/fd/3 3<&0 <&4 4<&- 5>&- > test.bin
} 4<&0 5>&1

dd_status=${PIPESTATUS[0]} cat_status=${PIPESTATUS[1]}
```

(`$PIPESTATUS` is bash-specific, but there are alternatives for other shells).

Above, both `dd` and `cat` will have the pipe open on their fd 3 (the writing end for `dd` and the reading end for `cat`) and they'll open `/dev/fd/3` giving them another fd on the pipe like in the workaround above. We use fds 4 and 5 to restore the original stdin and stdout for both (though here `cat`'s stdout is otherwise going to `test.bin`).

Comment: Why the `-f` in the `rm`? When can that be needed?

Comment: @terdon, you generally want `-f` in scripts, where `rm` is meant to work unattended. With `-f`, `rm` could prompt the user under some circumstances.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas This answer mostly works.  If `dd` fails right away (say for permissions failure or file not found), the script hangs.  I presume it is because the `cat` command is waiting for data in the pipe and not getting anything.  Thus the `wait` command is never reached.

Comment: @A.Que, if `dd` fails before it can open the pipe for writing, then the shell will block upon *opening* the pipe, before even starting `cat`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ok.  How does one recover from this failure mode?

Comment: @A.Que see edit.